# check engine Light 2015 Nissan Sentra - Needed help in Engine Diagnosis

Tags: nissan, cel, sentra

I am doing check engine light diagnosis on my **2015 Nissan Sentra**. Here the ODB Scanner Report

[image]

Based on report - It says MAF sensor wiring (it might be bad)
I have tested my MAF sensor wiring by starting the car and unplugging the wire. If the engine shuts down, then there is no problem with the wiring. For my case Engine has shut down as soon as wiring has removed. **Not a wiring issue** [I have come to know this via YouTube] correct me if am wrong or share me a DIY video of how to check this.

And as a Standard safety check earlier few days back there was issue sensor, facing sudden acceleration issues (even though no force applied gas petal). I cleaned it with an airflow cleaner. then on highway drives, check engine light has gone off.

So, this time i have also cleaned my airflow sensor.

Another thing this report says is about Cam shaft sensor bad, but based on my research if that sensor goes bad, for my car the car won't even start until sensor has been replaced & cleared the code. In my case my car starts fine & runs smoothly.

Another thing to look at it has controller area Network line malfunction - it means it has issue with ECM and ECM needs to be reprogrammed something like that
[This is something only Nissan dealers can do it. and fairly expensive]

**Any suggestions on how to proceed further, just worried if this minor issue can be high cost later. Do I need to take this to the Nissan mechanic for diagnosis because it might require ECM reprogramming**. check engine light is ON for more than 2 months now.

If the fix is simple, then it doesn't make spending too many bucks for that.  And doing DIY might be ideal

Note: I have noticed few changes like engine running high RPM on idle, its a bit more lound than usual and drop in fuel economy. And I feel for high RPM - throttle body cleaning is required. and for engine performce - engine oil might needs to be changed

Comment: Have you recently reset all of the error codes to make sure that these ones are current, or could these be from a long time ago?

Answer (score 0):

The first step in electronics diagnosis is to make sure your starting and charging systems are functioning properly. Don't waste time and money chasing problems that may not be there. C1109 suggests there are problems with the battery output. Maybe there is, maybe there's not but this is the first step. Before you do anything have your battery and charging system checked and then proceed diagnosing with a fully charged battery. Many times the ECU will report false codes when it's in low voltage.

The next step is to verify the other codes. One way to do this is to clear the codes and see which ones if any come back. The codes may have already been cleared when you checked or repaired the charging system because unhooking the battery clears the codes also. Then you may have to wait for the codes to reappear. But this time you no that false codes from a bad voltage supply isn't there.

Because you've had performance issues I'd expect some codes to return. Remember though that some communication codes show up simply because of scanner compatibility issues. Some codes will not return unless the vehicle is driven for a while, so give it a short ride before you post back here with your new list of codes.